# Find out the source control state of a ProjectItem from a Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, version-control, vsx

I'm currently developing a Visual Studio extension. For a new feature I need to find out whether a given ProjectItem (file) was modified (has "Pending Changes" since the last commit). For this I would like to query the source control provider.

- I already tried searching all the properties of the ProjectItem but there is nothing hidden in there.
- I also tried getting a service associated with source control from the Package.cs. I tried getting IVsSccManager2, IVsSccManager3 and IVsSccGlyphs. All return null (the test project is under source control). **edit:** I try to get these services by calling *GetService(typeof(IVsSccManager2))* inside my *Package.cs*. The source control plugin of my debugging session correctly shows the changed files at the time this is called.

I can't seem to find anything online about this topic. How can I find out the modified state? Is it even possible?

Comment: By 'modified, do you mean [checked out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.sourcecontrol.isitemcheckedout.aspx)?

Comment: @stuartd Good question, I'm referring to files that have been changed since the last commit and have "Pending Changes".

Comment: Check out the SourceControl interface in VS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/EnvDTE.SourceControl.aspx

Comment: What you can get is the VsStateIcon: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.vsstateicon.aspx and SccStatus but that may not be what you want. This icon can be retrieved using IVsSccManager2::GetSccGlyph. IVsSccManager2 should not be null. What code do you use to get a reference on IVsSccManager2?

Comment: @simon-mourier I tried to do this already, but retried it to be sure. I use the following code to get the service: GetService(typeof(IVsSccManager2)); I call it inside my Package.cs after the solution is loaded and I can use my source control plugin like normal. The plugin displays the changed files correctly.

Comment: @dbugger I tried to do this, but it doesn't really solve my problem. I don't just need to know if an item is under source control, I need to know if it was changed since the last commit. I think that can't be solved via this interface, right?

Comment: It should be `GetService(typeof(SVsSccManager))`, not `GetService(typeof(IVsSccManager2))`

Comment: @SimonMourier Great tip, thanks! Now I get the service and can call `GetSccGlyph(...)`. The return value is always `S_OK`, like defined, so I assumed the parameter `rgsiGlyphs` would be changed, but its not. How do I read it correctly?

Comment: Here is an example that demonstrates how to call it: http://pastebin.com/bqwHU08Z (mk is the item's moniker or url or file path)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks for the example code. My code is similar so I tried to map the first element of the array to a `VsStateIcon`, which works. So I tried to create a `SccStatus` object, but I can't seem to be able to do so. The only [resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa978287(v=vs.71).aspx) I could find doesn't explain how to use it. I'm only able to create a `__SccStatus` object (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.__sccstatus(v=vs.100).aspx)), but using that didn't work. [Here](http://pastebin.com/AKkADH0g) is my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After letting this topic sit for some time I recently came back to it and found the solution thanks to the help of my collegue. The problem was that I had no experience in bitwise comparison so I didn't know how to handle the response properly. Luckily my collegue gave me the right tip.

To interpret the result of status (thanks to @simon-mourier for the help on this code):

```
uint[] sccStatus = new uint[] { 0 };
if (VSConstants.S_OK == manager.GetSccGlyph(1, new[] { filePath }, new[] { VsStateIcon.STATEICON_NOSTATEICON }, sccStatus))
{
    __SccStatus status = (__SccStatus)sccStatus[0];
}
```

One has to do **bitwise comparison** with the state of `__SccStatus` you are looking for, for example:

```
if ((sccStatus[0] & (uint)__SccStatus.SCC_STATUS_RESERVED_2) != 0)
    return true;
```

The comparison returns `true` in case the state is set. If you need help on what specific state combinations can mean, just comment here and I can help on that.